# Should I use setState conditional updates in componentDidUpdate in React 16?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm using React 16 and need to call a conditional **setState** inside **componentDidUpdate**. **setState** is executed asynchronously. So, usually, if I need to use **state** to compute my next **state** I should use **updater** function as an argument to **setState**.
React 16 added a possibility to cancel a **setState** update by returning **null** from **setState**. So, should I use **updater** function to make a conditional **setState**?

Code with **updater**:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const prevValue = prevProps.value;
    this.setState((state, props) => {
        const nextValue = props.value;
        if (prevValue === nextValue) return null;
        const isIncreasing = prevValue < nextValue;
        if (prevState.isIncreasing === isIncreasing) return null;
        return { isIncreasing };
    });
}
```

Code without **updater**:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const prevValue = prevProps.value;
    const nextValue = this.props.value;
    if (prevValue === nextValue) return;
    const isIncreasing = prevValue < nextValue;
    if (prevState.isIncreasing === isIncreasing) return;
    this.setState({ isIncreasing });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no difference other than stylistically. Personally I prefer the second approach. Either way you will cause another render cycle so alternatively you could use `getDerivedStateFromProps` which will run before the component renders and doesn't require conditionals to prevent infinite loops:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return {
    prevValue: props.value,
    isIncreasing: props.value > state.prevValue, // First time will always be true since state.prevValue is undefined FYI
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks, getDerivedState can help me to avoid the second render! I was confused how to get prevProps in it. So, great idea!